# Data out of range with Indesign scripting, because of small page size

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm getting `Data out of range` with a Indesign jsx script.
My scripts stops at: `Line 102 Source: pageWidth = width;`

I think it's because of the margin is larger then the paper size. I tried to handle the scenario of the smallest paper size: `A11`, with a `if else statement`.

And I tried to remove the masterpage, with `app masterpages remove and pop`, but I don't know how to do that.

How can I give all the paper sizes a margin of "5mm", and the "A11" a margin of "0mm"? I'm using Indesign CS6 on Windows 7.

This is my **JSON data**:

```
var papersizes = [
     {
       "name": "4A0",
       "length": 2378,
       "width": 1682
     },
     {
       "name": "2A0",
       "length": 1682,
       "width": 1189
     },
     {
       "name": "A0",
       "length": 1189,
       "width": 841
     },
     {
       "name": "A1",
       "length": 841,
       "width": 594
     },
     {
       "name": "A2",
       "length": 594,
       "width": 420
     },
     {
       "name": "A3",
       "length": 420,
       "width": 297
     },
     {
       "name": "A4",
       "length": 297,
       "width": 210
     },
     {
       "name": "A5",
       "length": 210,
       "width": 148
     },
     {
       "name": "A6",
       "length": 148,
       "width": 105
     },
     {
       "name": "A7",
       "length": 105,
       "width": 74
     },
     {
       "name": "A8",
       "length": 74,
       "width": 52
     },
     {
       "name": "A9",
       "length": 52,
       "width": 37
     },
     {
       "name": "A10",
       "length": 37,
       "width": 26
     },
     {
       "name": "A11",
       "length": 26,
       "width": 18
     }
    ];
```

This is my **code**:

```
var bleed = "4mm";
var margin = "10mm";

for (index = 0; index < papersizes.length; ++index) {       
        papersize = papersizes[index];
        name = papersize["name"];
        length = papersize["length"];
        width = papersize["width"];

        var doc = app.documents.add();

        with(doc.viewPreferences) {
            horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.MILLIMETERS;
            verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.MILLIMETERS;
        }

        with(doc.documentPreferences) {
            pageHeight = length;
            //Here does my script stops
            pageWidth = width;
            pageOrientation = PageOrientation.PORTRAIT;
            pagesPerDocument = 1;

            documentBleedBottomOffset = bleed;
            documentBleedTopOffset = bleed;
            documentBleedInsideOrLeftOffset = bleed;
            documentBleedOutsideOrRightOffset = bleed;
        }

        //Here I try to handle the paper size
        if(name != "A11") {
            with (doc.pages.item(0).marginPreferences){
                bottom = margin;
                //When document.documentPreferences.facingPages == true,
                //"left" means inside; "right" means outside.
                left = margin;
                right = margin;
                top = margin;
            }
        } else {
            with (doc.pages.item(0).marginPreferences){     
                bottom = 0;
                //When document.documentPreferences.facingPages == true,
                //"left" means inside; "right" means outside.
                left = 0;
                right = 0;
                top = 0;
            }
        }               

        //If the active document has not been saved (ever), save it.
        if(app.activeDocument.saved == false){
            //If you do not provide a file name, InDesign will display the Save dialog box.
            app.activeDocument.save(new File("C:/IndesignOutput/DIN_"+name+"_"+length+"mm_"+width+"mm.indd"));
            app.activeDocument.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Does it work when you do this manually?

Comment: When I create a A11 paper with 0 margin from the GUI, then it's possible. So why doesn't it work with a script?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, you can't change the document size because of the default marges. So yes: changing them should make it work. However, you must change them *before* attempting to set this small size, not *afterwards*.

But, alas, that's not the only thing. As it appears, it is not enough to change just the current *page* – resizing a document also resizes its master spreads, and so you need to change those as well.

My usual trick to set a number of items to use the same properties is this:

```
// doc.masterSpreads.item(0).pages.everyItem().marginPreferences.properties = { ... };
```

... but, quite surprising, `everyItem` does nothing here! So you have to manually loop over the pages in `masterSpreads`. Fortunately, you don't have to change the first page of the document, because by default it has this first master spread applied.

It still didn't work, and after a bit of trial-and-error I found there is *another* set of margins that you need to reset: the document's own defaults. (No idea why. Maybe in case you delete all master spreads, or something odd like that, and the margin values still need to 'live' somewhere.)

This works for me:

```
length = 26;
width = 18;
bleed = "4mm";
margin = "10mm";

var doc = app.documents.add();

with(doc.viewPreferences) {
    horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.MILLIMETERS;
    verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.MILLIMETERS;
}

doc.marginPreferences.properties = { top:0, bottom:0, left:0, right: 0 };
for (i=0; i<doc.masterSpreads.item(0).pages.length; i++)
doc.masterSpreads.item(0).pages.item(i).marginPreferences.properties = {
    bottom:0,
    //When document.documentPreferences.facingPages == true,
    //"left" means inside; "right" means outside.
    left:0,
    right:0,
    top:0
};

with(doc.documentPreferences) {
    pageOrientation = PageOrientation.PORTRAIT;
    pagesPerDocument = 1;

    documentBleedBottomOffset = bleed;
    documentBleedTopOffset = bleed;
    documentBleedInsideOrLeftOffset = bleed;
    documentBleedOutsideOrRightOffset = bleed;

    pageHeight = length;
    pageWidth = width;
}
```

Checking the name, by the way, is just fine if you know in advance which name will cause the problem. But it may be better to find out below what sizes (either width or height) the problem occurs, and set the margins to `0` if either size is too low.